# setTimeout being called multiple times

Tags: javascript, logic, p5.js

I can't figure out why setTimeout is being called multiple times in my code.
Here's a snippet of the code with what I thought was irrelevant removed:

```
let dead;

    setup()
    {
        dead = false;
    }
    
    draw()
    {
        if(fell == true)
        {
            dead = true;
        }
        mechanics();
    }
    
    function mechanics()
    {
        
        let triggerVar;
        
        if(dead == true)
        {   
            triggerVar = 1;
            
            dead = false;
        }
        
        if(triggerVar == 1)
        {
            setTimeout(resetG, 1500);
            triggerVar = 0;
        }
    }
    
    function resetG()
    {
        lives -= 1;
        position = 0;
    }
```

I can't tell what I'm doing wrong because whenever the character dies and setTimeout is called, it is actually not only called after the delay but also for the exact same duration after it is triggered. So in this case it is triggered first after 1500 millis and then every frame for another 1500 millis.

Comment: Where are you calling these functions? Maybe the function definition is correct but how you are calling them is what matters. A while loop somewhere in your code, maybe?

Comment: @SaulMartinez The mechanics(); function is called in draw(); every frame.

Comment: What I mean is, could you also post the rest of the code? Whatever you left out is crucial. (I think you left some code out since "fell" is being called at ```if(fell == true)``` but never initialized, I assume there's more. You are describing a looping behaviour but there is not any looping structure in the code you shared).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the problem, which was not with the code I posted. The problem was that the constructor code that makes the object that changes dead to true if certain conditions are met was being called every frame from the moment it triggered death until the first instance of setTimeout kicked in, which means setTimeout was called every frame for 1500 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you mechanics() function is called multiple times, you may give a variable to the settimeout like:

```
let timeoutID= setTimeout(resetG, 1500);
```

And in the proper place to clear it, for example after lifecycle

```
clearTimeout(timeoutID);
```

Comment: Hi @anthony-lu Yes, mechanics() is being called every frame by draw(), that's why I added triggerVar to stop setTimeout() from being called every frame after it was called once. But it seems like I'm doing it wrong!

Comment: try to make let triggerVar a global variable, because every time you run mechanics, it is reinitiated

Comment: Great point, I did it. But it did not stop resetG() from being called every frame for 1500 milliseconds.